# Forcing a probabilistic result output in solr

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

I was trying to force a probabilistic result output in solr. i.e x% (say k/n) of the page results have attribute A. I am not sure if there is a straight forward way of doing this.

I am trying the query re-ranking approach, where-in I wanted to boost the documents with attribute A in the first solr query. This should ensure that at least k or more documents with attribute A are at the top. I then wanted to run another query, which would pick just the k elements, and then pick rest n-k elements in the normal score order and return the score sorted output of these.

I am however facing the issue that if attribute A is very frequent, then I might end up bringing too many Attribute A documents in the first query and due to this wont be able to decide the number of documents to choose to run the second query

I am still new to solr, and hopefully am overthinking this. Nonetheless, have any of you had similar problem with solr, and have found a low latency solution for this?

Comment: Can you bring an example of what would rank higher that what other element and why, in an imaginary dataset?

Comment: @LeftyGBalogh Hey, sure. So, if we take freshness of the document as the attribute metric then, I want the search results to be relevant but have a probabilistic tinge to it.  i.e if we output 10 results per page, and we set the result freshness probability to 0.2 then there should be atleast 2 out of those 10 results which have the fresh attribute. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I guess a weighted search would do the trick, if I considered all your criteria appropriately. If you load the sample data I created below into a demo core, and run an edismax search so that you weigh relevance at 0.8 and freshness at 0.2, the relevant fresh answers come out at the top. 
[image]

The search URL is as follows:`http://<solr_server>.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8983/solr/gettingstarted/select?defType=edismax&indent=on&q=*:*&qf=relevance^0.8%20AND%20freshness^0.2&rows=10&start=0&wt=json`

Please note I limited the resultset to the first ten.

The response header with the results looks like:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":6,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "defType":"edismax",
      "indent":"on",
      "qf":"relevance^0.8 AND freshness^0.2",
      "start":"0",
      "rows":"10",
      "wt":"json",
      "_":"1477363414109"}},
  "response":{"numFound":35,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"1",
        "name":["JBL Professional Audio"],
        "relevance":[true],
        "freshness":[true],
        "_version_":1549127868117680128},
      {
        "id":"2",
        "name":["Versatile Multilayer Disc"],
        "relevance":[true],
        "freshness":[true],
        "_version_":1549127868288598016},
      {
        "id":"3",
        "name":["Key finder"],
        "relevance":[true],
        "freshness":[false],
        "_version_":1549127868290695168},
      {
        "id":"4",
        "name":["MiniDisc"],
        "relevance":[true],
        "freshness":[false],
        "_version_":1549127868291743744},
      {
        "id":"5",
        "name":["Entertainment center"],
        "relevance":[true],
        "freshness":[false],
        "_version_":1549127868292792320},
      {
        "id":"6",
        "name":["TV gateway"],
        "relevance":[true],
        "freshness":[false],
        "_version_":1549127868294889472},
      {
        "id":"7",
        "name":["Da-Lite Lecterns, Podiums, Racks"],
        "relevance":[true],
        "freshness":[false],
        "_version_":1549127868295938048},
      {
        "id":"8",
        "name":["American Dynamics CCTV Products"],
        "relevance":[true],
        "freshness":[false],
        "_version_":1549127868301180928},
      {
        "id":"9",
        "name":["K-box"],
        "relevance":[true],
        "freshness":[false],
        "_version_":1549127868302229504},
      {
        "id":"10",
        "name":["Wife acceptance factor"],
        "relevance":[true],
        "freshness":[false],
        "_version_":1549127868303278080}]
  }}
```

The sample data set that you can load from Documents is the following:

```
<add>
<doc>
<field name="id">1</field>
<field name="name">JBL Professional Audio</field>
<field name="relevance">true</field>
<field name="freshness">true</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">2</field>
<field name="name">Versatile Multilayer Disc</field>
<field name="relevance">true</field>
<field name="freshness">true</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">3</field>
<field name="name">Key finder</field>
<field name="relevance">true</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">4</field>
<field name="name">MiniDisc</field>
<field name="relevance">true</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">5</field>
<field name="name">Entertainment center</field>
<field name="relevance">true</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">6</field>
<field name="name">TV gateway</field>
<field name="relevance">true</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">7</field>
<field name="name">Da-Lite Lecterns, Podiums, Racks</field>
<field name="relevance">true</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">8</field>
<field name="name">American Dynamics CCTV Products</field>
<field name="relevance">true</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">9</field>
<field name="name">K-box</field>
<field name="relevance">true</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">10</field>
<field name="name">Wife acceptance factor</field>
<field name="relevance">true</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">11</field>
<field name="name">J</field>
<field name="relevance">true</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">12</field>
<field name="name">Location awareness</field>
<field name="relevance">true</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">13</field>
<field name="name">Hybrid Broadcast Broadband TV</field>
<field name="relevance">true</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">14</field>
<field name="name">Comparison of digital media players</field>
<field name="relevance">true</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">15</field>
<field name="name">Coupon-eligible converter box</field>
<field name="relevance">true</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">16</field>
<field name="name">Crown Audio</field>
<field name="relevance">false</field>
<field name="freshness">true</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">17</field>
<field name="name">Q</field>
<field name="relevance">false</field>
<field name="freshness">true</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">18</field>
<field name="name">Surround sound</field>
<field name="relevance">false</field>
<field name="freshness">true</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">19</field>
<field name="name">Digital Living Network Alliance</field>
<field name="relevance">false</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">20</field>
<field name="name">EcoCute</field>
<field name="relevance">false</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">21</field>
<field name="name">TV gateway</field>
<field name="relevance">false</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">22</field>
<field name="name">List of smart TV platforms and middleware software</field>
<field name="relevance">false</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">23</field>
<field name="name">Predicta</field>
<field name="relevance">false</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">24</field>
<field name="name">AMX Control Systems</field>
<field name="relevance">false</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">25</field>
<field name="name">Batteriser</field>
<field name="relevance">false</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">26</field>
<field name="name">Audio equipment</field>
<field name="relevance">false</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">27</field>
<field name="name">EcoCute</field>
<field name="relevance">false</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">28</field>
<field name="name">Elmo Document Cameras</field>
<field name="relevance">false</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">29</field>
<field name="name">Lab Gruppen Audio</field>
<field name="relevance">false</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">30</field>
<field name="name">Direct-drive turntable</field>
<field name="relevance">false</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">31</field>
<field name="name">Wearable Technology Show</field>
<field name="relevance">false</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">32</field>
<field name="name">Power cord</field>
<field name="relevance">false</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">33</field>
<field name="name">MiniDisc</field>
<field name="relevance">false</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">34</field>
<field name="name">Quattron</field>
<field name="relevance">false</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
<doc>
<field name="id">35</field>
<field name="name">I</field>
<field name="relevance">false</field>
<field name="freshness">false</field>
</doc>
</add>
```

Is this what you had in mind?